# Java crypto convert raw bytes to PublicKey and vise versa

Tags: java, cryptography

I'm trying to make a `java.security.PublicKey` from a `byte[]` that is just a raw key—it's not in X.509 or ASN.1. In other languages, people are using libsodium, which just gives them a raw byte[]. I also need to be able to convert my `java.security.PublicKey` to a `byte[]` for them to consume. It seems that `java.security` goes to great lengths to make that challenging, instead wanting me to rely on pre-encoded X509 `SubjectPublicKeyInfo`. Am I missing a simple answer here?

Comment: The phrase "raw key" is not really meaningful. Public keys have different formats and you must know what the format is. So, what format is the key in?

Comment: Did you notice that libodium does support **only** Ed25519 keys? (see https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/public-key_cryptography/public-key_signatures)

Comment: A public key consists of multiple elements depending on the cipher (for RSA it is modulo and exponent), so the *raw* format is somehow serialized form of the elements or optionally some metadata.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Libsodium](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/), like all NaCl derivatives, uses [Curve25519](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve25519) for its crypto operations, i.e. X25519 for DH key exchange and Ed25519 for signing.
Java supports X25519 since [version 11](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/324), Ed25519 is supported since [version 15](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/339). Both functionalities are provided by the SunEC provider.

For the import/export of raw keys it is easiest to use some [BouncyCastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html) functions. The following code creates for X25519 (Java 11 and higher) a public test key in X.509 format and exports the raw 32 bytes key from it. Afterwards the raw key is imported into a X.509 key again:

```
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

import org.bouncycastle.asn1.edec.EdECObjectIdentifiers;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.AlgorithmIdentifier;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.SubjectPublicKeyInfo;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.X25519PublicKeyParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.util.PublicKeyFactory;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex;
...
// Generate public test key in X.509 format
PublicKey publicKey = loadPublicKey("X25519");
byte[] publicKeyBytes = publicKey.getEncoded();
System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(publicKeyBytes)); // X.509-key, check this in an ASN.1 Parser, e.g. https://lapo.it/asn1js/

// PublicKey to raw key
X25519PublicKeyParameters x25519PublicKeyParameters = (X25519PublicKeyParameters)PublicKeyFactory.createKey(publicKeyBytes);
byte[] rawKey = x25519PublicKeyParameters.getEncoded();
System.out.println(Hex.toHexString(rawKey)); // equals the raw 32 bytes key from the X.509 key

// Raw key to PublicKey
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("X25519");
SubjectPublicKeyInfo subjectPublicKeyInfo = new SubjectPublicKeyInfo(new AlgorithmIdentifier(EdECObjectIdentifiers.id_X25519), rawKey);
X509EncodedKeySpec x509EncodedKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(subjectPublicKeyInfo.getEncoded());
publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(x509EncodedKeySpec);
publicKeyBytes = publicKey.getEncoded();
System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(publicKeyBytes)); // equals the X.509 key from above
```

where the X.509 test key is created with:

```
private static PublicKey loadPublicKey(String algorithm) throws Exception {
    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(algorithm);
    KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
    return keyPair.getPublic();
}
```

And analog for Ed25519 (Java 15 and higher).

X25519 and Ed25519 can also both be implemented *solely* with classes from BouncyCastle, e.g. `org.bouncycastle.math.ec.rfc7748.X25519` (key agreement), `org.bouncycastle.crypto.generators.X25519KeyPairGenerator` (key generation), `org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.X25519PublicKeyParameters` (key container), and analog classes for Ed25519.