# String to PrivateKey Ed25519

Tags: java, private-key, ed25519

I have a private key as a String and I want to convert it to `PrivateKey`

```
String privateKey = "Y2E3YjYwYzRjMDRjMjk1ZDQ5ZTQzM2RlMTdjZjVkNGE0NGFjYzJmM2IzOWExNWZhMjViNGE4ZWJiZDBiMDVkYTIwNGU4MWE3ZWZmMTQ0NGE2ZmM2NjExNzRmNTY4M2I0YmYyMTk5YTkyY2UzOWRkZjdmMzhkNTFjYTNmM2Q3ZDU";

byte[] pkcs8EncodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateKey);

PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(pkcs8EncodedBytes);

PrivateKey pkey = KeyFactory.getInstance("Ed25519") //NoSuchAlgorithmException
                            .generatePrivate(keySpec);
```

But I get this error:

`java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Ed25519 KeyFactory not available`

at `KeyFactory.getInstance("Ed25519")`

I'm using Java-10

Comment: Ed25519 is supported as of Java 15. For earlier Java versions BouncyCastle is an option. However, your key is Base64 decoded 4 bytes, which is too small for an Ed25519 key.

Comment: In Java10 you can use only those KeyFactory algorithms https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/specs/security/standard-names.html#keyfactory-algorithms

Comment: @Topaco, about the key, I know, I just putted something random, to not put the real value here. About the BouncyCastle, I tried to find it on mvnrepository, but I don't know which one to choose. Can you help me?

Comment: You don't need (and shouldn't) post a _real_ key, but you should specify the key format (or alternatively share a _test_ key). Assuming you want to import the _raw_ key, you can use BouncyCastle (i.e. the provider jar, [bcprov](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on)), s. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68484321/9014097) for a code sample. Alternatively, you can use the prefix `0x302e020100300506032b657004220420` for a _raw to PKCS#8_ conversion followed by a standard import using `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec` (this prefix only works for the _raw private Ed25519_ key).

Comment: @Topaco, I putted a test key. Since the raw java 10 don't work. My intention is the sign some data using that private key with algorithm Ed25519

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The posted key is double encoded, first hex, then Base64. Note that the double encoding is not necessary. If the key is Base64 and hex decoded, the result is a 64 bytes key.

From this 64 bytes key the first 32 bytes are the secret key and the following 32 bytes are the public key. More details about this format can be found [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/54367).

Import, signing and verification with BouncyCastle are possible with `Ed25519PrivateKeyParameters`, `Ed25519PublicKeyParameters` and `Ed25519Signer` classes:

```java
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Base64;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.Signer;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.Ed25519PrivateKeyParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.Ed25519PublicKeyParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.signers.Ed25519Signer;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex;

// Base64, hex decode
String keyHexBase64 ="Y2E3YjYwYzRjMDRjMjk1ZDQ5ZTQzM2RlMTdjZjVkNGE0NGFjYzJmM2IzOWExNWZhMjViNGE4ZWJiZDBiMDVkYTIwNGU4MWE3ZWZmMTQ0NGE2ZmM2NjExNzRmNTY4M2I0YmYyMTk5YTkyY2UzOWRkZjdmMzhkNTFjYTNmM2Q3ZDU";
byte[] key = Hex.decode(new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(keyHexBase64), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

// Separate secret and public key
ByteBuffer keyBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(key);
byte[] secretKey = new byte[32];
keyBuffer.get(secretKey);
byte[] publicKey = new byte[keyBuffer.remaining()];
keyBuffer.get(publicKey);

// Signing
byte[] message = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
Ed25519PrivateKeyParameters secretKeyParameters = new Ed25519PrivateKeyParameters(secretKey, 0);
Signer signer = new Ed25519Signer();
signer.init(true, secretKeyParameters);
signer.update(message, 0, message.length);
byte[] signature = signer.generateSignature();
System.out.println("Signature (hex): " + Hex.toHexString(signature));

// Verification
Ed25519PublicKeyParameters publicKeyParameters = new Ed25519PublicKeyParameters(publicKey, 0);
Signer verifier = new Ed25519Signer();
verifier.init(false, publicKeyParameters);
verifier.update(message, 0, message.length);
boolean verified = verifier.verifySignature(signature); // Signature (hex): 2aa31bb14799a00ac1129bdd6773a8481f0fd7e829d59f6fccc81021bf21e397dc5d17362d342615a5500598542586cad8891f984bdb90ec0c80b48eb638df07
System.out.println("Verification: " + verified); // Verification: true
```

Regarding BouncyCastle, *bcprov-jdk15on* is required, which can be loaded from the [Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on) or from the [BouncyCastle website](https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html).